# using embedded amqp swith spring boot and camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, amqp

I want to integration test a custom camel component and therefor need an embedded/in memory messanging I can easily use to test from/to endpoints.

I am hoping that I can achieve this via spring-boot-amqp-starter.
I used [this example](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-boot-embedded-activemq-configuration-example/) for a start, which has the dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and the config:

```
spring:
  activemq:
    broker-url: vm://embedded?broker.persistent=false,useShutdownHook=false
   // ...
```

This is working, when I use regular Listener annotations in spring, I have a sender using the template and a consumer logging the messages.

Now I go one step further and use camel, but it does not recognize the `vm:embedded` broker but tries to connect to tcp://localhost, which is not running.

```
return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("activemq:foo").to("log:sample");

            from("timer:bar").setBody(constant("Hello from Camel")).to("activemq:foo");
        }
    };
```

How can I configure activemq-camel to use the embedded broker?

*Update:*

I use dependency management imports for `spring-boot-dependencies` (1.5.9)
and `camel-spring-boot-dependencies` (2.20.1).

Comment: What versions of all those tech are you using

Comment: see update on question

Comment: Whats the version of ActiveMQ client

Comment: client version org.apache.activemq.activemq-client: 5.14.5

Comment: Try with newer ActiveMQ version, we fixed something about Spring Boot a while back.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, switching manually to "activemq-camel:5.15.2" solved this. Do you want to create an answer for good karma, or should I?
The latest version should be part of the camel-spring-boot-dependencies though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in newer versions of activemq-camel when you use that with Spring Boot. Now the activemq-camel component will honor the spring boot configuration of the `spring.activemq.*` settings.

Comment: Confirm: works with 5.15.2. Had to set it manually because it was not part of camel spring boot dependencies in 01/2018